# Dummit and Foote: conjugate elements and conjugate subgroups have the same order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition*, Dummit and Foote.

The statement is from Corollary 14 in Section 4.4 "If $K$ is any subgroup of the group $G$ and $g\in G$, then $K\cong gKg^{-1}$. Conjugate elements and conjugate subgroups have the same order."

**My Question**: Does "the order of conjugate elements" refer to the number of conjugates of a given element $g\in G$ (i.e., the cardinality of the orbit of $g$)? If yes, then what is the conjugate subgroups here then? This is not the first time I got confused by Dummit and Foote-any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have my copy D&F handy at the moment, but I believe they're saying that for an element $k \in K$, the conjugate $gkg^{-1}$ has the same order as $k$ for any $g \in G$. Similarly, the order of the conjugate subgroup $gKg^{-1}$ is the same as the order of $K$ for any $g \in G$.

Comment: @user1090793 masterfully deciphered-thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

> Does "the order of conjugate elements" refer to the number of conjugates of a given element $g \in G$ (i.e., the cardinality of the orbit of $g$)?

*No*.  The "order of an element" refers to the number of its powers (finite order is the least $n > 0$ making the $n$th power trivial).  The order of an element is not usually equal to the number of elements conjugate to it: the order of $g$ counts the number of different $g^n$ as $n$ runs through $\mathbf Z$, while the order of the conjugacy class of $g$ refers to the number of different $tgt^{-1}$ as $t$ runs over $G$.  It's not the same thing.
Nobody ever calls the number of conjugates of an element in a group the "order" of that element.

> If yes, then what is the conjugate subgroups here then?

The "order of a subgroup" is the number of elements in it.  If $K = gHg^{-1}$ then $H$ and $K$ have the same cardinality (the same order).  If $y = gxg^{-1}$ then $x$ and $y$ have the same number of different powers (the same order as elements of the group).